# Concatenar en PHP

Tags: php

Buenas, estoy empezando en la programación en PHP y hoy nos han mandado un pequeño ejercicio simple para practicar. Lo que nos pide es que los dos `echo` sean exactamente iguales, pero en el primer `echo` de la variable `$sql` si me muestra '2DAW' con las comillas simples y en el otro `echo` en el cual concateno la variable `$aula` me lo visualiza sin comillas simples.

```
<?php
    echo "<h3>SIN VARIABLE</h3>";
    $sql = "select * <br>
            from alumnos <br>
            where clase = '2DAW'";
    echo $sql;
    echo '<br><br>';

    echo "<h3>CON VARIABLE</h3>";
    $aula = "2DAW";
    $sql = "select * <br>
            from alumnos <br>
            where clase = ".$aula;
    echo $sql;
    echo '<br><br>';
  ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

las comillas en `$aula = "2DAW";` denotan que es texto, más no son parte de la cadena como tal, si quieres que aparezcan las comillas tienes que ponerlas dentro del texto `$aula = "'2DAW'";`

Comment: Vale gracias, tiene su lógica :)